# Delay before Firefox starts downloading

Tags: 12.10, firefox, downloads

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with XFCE 4.10.  Firefox version 20.0.

Whenever I try to download any files (eg, right-click and download, anything like that), there's a significant delay (~15 seconds).  It doesn't matter how large the file is -- a 20kB file has a delay, and so does a 10MB file.  I've tried clearing out the list of previously-downloaded files, but that didn't help.

I also have Chromium installed, but it doesn't have the same delay problem.

Any suggestions?

**Currently mounted drives/devices**

```
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
/dev/sda5 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/home/xxxxxx/.Private on /home/xxxxxx type ecryptfs
    (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,
    ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/xxxxxx/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse 
    (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxxxxx)
/dev/sda3 on /media/xxxxxx/8C4896FB4896E36E type fuseblk 
    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/xxxxxx/DATAPART1 type fuseblk 
    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

This is a dual-boot Windows 7/Ubuntu 12.10 machine, and `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sdb1` are the Windows volumes `C:` and `D:` respectively.

Comment: Do you see the delay when you run Firefox in safe mode? Press Alt+H+R to restart Firefox with add-ons disabled.

Comment: Do you happen to have any remote filesystems mounted? I noticed a similar delay elsewhere, that turned out to be caused by my NAS waking up.

Comment: The same delay happens in safe mode.  I sometimes have some Novell drives mounted, but they're not mounted now, and I'm still seeing the delay.  I'll add the results of `mount` to my question, in case they're salient.

Comment: You may be better off asking this question [here](https://support.mozilla.org) as it appears to be a Firefox issue. However, I would be curious to see what happens if you start Firefox with a blank profile: `firefox -ProfileManager`

Comment: @Jos -- It's a Firefox issue, yes, but it's only happening for me on Ubuntu 12.10/XFCE. My Windows machine at home works fine, but both my work machine and my laptop (both Ubuntu 12.10 with XFCE) exhibit the delay.  Also, Firefox with a brand-new blank profile *still* exhibits the delay.  I'll contact Mozilla, too, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was not necessarily a Firefox issue. I updated some other packages and the problem went away after the reboot.  I can't say for sure what the issue was, but it's solved now.